# Postgresql: computing AVG between rows with given IDs

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql.
Let's say I have a transactions_table with just two columns:
- aggregated month number (integer)
- value of transactions for given month (float)

Tricky part: for some months there have been no transactions. Such months are NOT in table at all. I.e. I might have data for aggregated month number 1, 2, 7, 9 (no row for month 3, 4, 5, 6, 8) etc.

I need to make a new averages_table, with average transactions value from previous 12 months for each month in transactions_table (obviously, without aggregated months < 12).
I need average for previous 12 months, not previous 12 rows.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should limit the data to desired period in a derived table (a subquery in the FROM clause) and calculate averages on the limited dataset, like this:

```
select month, product_id, avg(transaction_value) 
from (
    select month, product_id, transaction_value 
    from transactions
    where month between 1806 - 12 and 1806
    ) s
group by month, product_id
```

where `1806` is the last month of the desired period (probably a query parameter).

Comment: Apparently, I have 'oversimplified' my example.

Comment: That's why it's always worth delivering: simplified table(s) definition, sample data and expected results.

Comment: I have 'oversimplified' my example. I also have a column 'product_id' in transactions_table. There are ~50 000 different products. I need to compute average for last 12 months for each of those 50 000 products. Therefore, solutions based on appending 'missing' months with 0 value of transactions did not work for me. I was thinking of some solution following logic: SELECT a.month, a.product_id, average(transaction_value) FROM (SELECT b.month, b.product_id, transaction_value WHERE b.month BETWEEN (a.month, a.month - 12) and b.product_id = a.product_id). I just don't know how to do it in SQL...

Comment: klin - I did eventually use your first suggestion (creating additional table, filling in "missing" months with zero data). I had to play with table indexing & query efficiency to make it work reasonably, but eventually succeed.